# Transpile every TypeScript file to its equivalent JavaScript file in a project

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig, tsc

I want to transpile every `.ts` file in my server folder to an equivalent `.js` file. Basically, all I'm trying to achieve is transpiling a `.ts` file to a `.js` file minus the type annotations.

When I try simple `tsc server/index.ts` with the most basic `tsconfig.json` it does the trick but converts all promises and imports to weird unreadable JavaScript.

Is there a way to transpile every `.ts` file within a project to its equivalent JavaScript file with ES6 imports and `async` `await` preserved?

Comment: I suggest you share the tsconfig.json file as part of your question.